# Aggregate (RF) Variable Importance for Many Forests

Tags: r, random-forest, cbind

I have been testing random forests on one dataset.  I would like to output the variable importance of all RFs in one data frame.  Something like:

```
forests <- grep("rf", ls(), value=T)
importances <- do.call(cbind, lapply(forests, importance))
```

which throws an error:

```
Error in UseMethod("importance") : no applicable method for 'importance' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I tried converting `forests` to a list, but that didn't help either.

Example:

```
rf10 <- randomForest(mpg ~., mtcars, ntree=10)
rf100 <- randomForest(mpg ~., mtcars, ntree=100)
cbind(importance(rf10), importance(rf100))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do instead

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(forests, function(x) importance(get(x))))
```

The return value from grep was a list of variable names, not the variables themselves. When you did `importance(x)`, it was for example doing `importance("rf10")`. You should be using the object as the parameter, and not the object's name. `get(x)` returns the reference object for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @jav.  That was embarrassingly simple.